# How to convert buttons in an image into true clickable buttons on a web site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, web

For a website, when people load a page, there is an animation with buttons inside which appear. You can see a screenshot of the animation below.

Once the animation is finished, I want the user to be able to click on one of them. How can I do this ? Is existing a library, a suitable language, or a specific technology to complete this ?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if possible, edit the video and crop it.

Add the buttons using simple HTML.
I’m sorry if that isn’t possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I'm going to modify the video and add the buttons under it. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome! Always there to help! Upvote the answer if it was truly helpful

Comment: Are you looking for a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way to get the animation to respond to click events (like a button) would be to set up a mouse event listener in javascript, it will get fired every time someone clicks on the page.

Basically, within the click handler, you will compare the click location of the mouse to known screen coordinates of the buttons - if they match - trigger an event.

The hard bit comes with finding the coordinates of the buttons - very easy if the animation is drawn on a canvas - a bit harder if it's just an image.

Comment: I thank you really much for your advice. Actually, it is a video. What do you mean by 'canvas' ?